# When is a function differentiable

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a function 
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\quad0&(x,y)=(0,0)\\\dfrac{x^3y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0).
\end{cases}$$
I know what $f$ is continous at the point because the limit of $f$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ exist: did go to the origin by the $x$- and $y$-axis and all lines through origin. Since the limit exists, then $f$ is continuous and the partial derivatives exist in this point. But why isn't $f$ differentiable in $(0,0)$?

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be differentiable at $(0, 0)$? Are you familiar with the definition?

Comment: that the function must be continous on the domain and that the limit of the difference quotient of the function must exist?

Comment: It's not clear whether you already proved that $f$ is not differentiable but expected $f$ to be differentiable from the existance of partial derivates and continuity, or you are simply asking to prove that $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: For the function to be differentiable the partial derivatives have to be continuous at that point. Are the partial derivatives continuous at the origin?
@boywholived You should reconsider your comment. Future people might search this question and find this MSE thread. How delighted would they be to find your comment then?

Comment: @Fantini Not really, that's sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: @Kim Indeed, the limit of the difference quotient must exist. What you need to do is to show it does not exist. Can you do that?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś You're right, but that is much easier to check than cranking up the definition.

Comment: http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_partial_derivatives_not_implies_differentiable

Comment: @Fantini Well yes, but it can only prove differentiability, not *lack* thereof. Failure of a sufficient condition does not imply the fact does not hold. It's sufficient for function to be constant to be continuous, but there surely are nonconstant continuous functions.

Comment: @boywholived Existance does not imply differentiability, existance **and** continuity, on the other hand, does. In fact, it's enough for one partial derivative to be continuous IIRC.

Comment: I think you also need the partial derivatives to exist in a neighborhood of the point

Comment: i am getting that the limit of the difference quotient exist :/ @MarcinŁoś

Comment: Please show us your work in that case.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś. By reading the question I think the OP believes that existence of continuity of f and existence of partial derivatives  at a point implies differentiability. I just wanted to point out to the OP that it is not true, nothing more.

Comment: @boywholived I may have missed the intent of your comment. Sorry.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Could you help me with this? I did get stuck and confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$, and partial derivatives exist:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{0, 0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f\left(h, 0\right)-f\left(0, 0\right)}{h}=\frac{0-0}{h}=0
$$

Similarily, $D_y f(0, 0) = 0$. The definition of differentiability implies existence of the following limit:
$$
\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}
\frac{f(x, y) - f(0, 0) - 
x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(0, 0\right) - 
y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(0, 0\right)}{\left|(x, y)\right|}=
\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}}
$$

I claim it does not exist. Let $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin \theta$ and let $r\to 0$. The above limit becomes
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}
\frac{r^5\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\left(r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta\right)^{5/2}}=
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^5\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^5}=\lim_{r\to 0}\cos\theta\sin\theta
$$

which clearly depends on $\theta$.

Or, if you prefer, you can just explicitly choose two different directions and show they give different answers, e.g. $(x, y) = (0, t)$, $(x, y) = (t, t)$.

Comment: how did you get |(x,y)| to (x^2+y^2)^(5/2)`? Should it not be (x^2+y^2)^(1/2) since the 3 term from right is equal to zero? and why do you have | .. | on the numerator ?

Comment: $|(x,y)$ is indeed $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, but the $f$ itself has $(x^2+y^2)^2$ in the denumerator. And the absolute value in the numerator, while correct, is not necessary, and possibly misleading, I'll remove it.

Comment: oh, i did forget the denumerator in f :) now everything is clear! thanks again @MarcinŁoś